# Conolutional Neural Network: float() argument must be a string or a number?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, keras-layer

I want to train my data with a convolutional neural network (CNN),I start  with reshaping my data than creating my model:

```
model = Sequential()
input_traces = Input(shape=(3253,))

model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, border_mode='same', 
activation='relu',input_dim=input_traces))                      
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=
['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=15, nb_epoch=30, show_accuracy=True, 
validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

But this code gives  me this error:

```
CNN_Based_Attack.py:139: UserWarning: Update your `Conv1D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv1D(activation="relu", input_shape=(None, /in..., padding="same", filters=32, kernel_size=3)`
  model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, border_mode='same', activation='relu',input_dim=input_traces))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN_Based_Attack.py", line 139, in <module>
    model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=3, border_mode='same', activation='relu',input_dim=input_traces))
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 430, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 557, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 134, in build
    constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 390, in add_weight
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/initializers.py", line 200, in __call__
    scale /= max(1., float(fan_in + fan_out) / 2)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I really don't understand this error. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you should use Input. Input is a layer in Keras, and input_shape parameter to Convolution1D is supposed to be **list of integers** (and this is a reason of the error, since the code tries to use conversion to float on these integers, but you provided Input object instead, which cannot be casted to float), not Input layer.